# Stopping condition for when the last line of a file is blank C++

Tags: c++, file, blank-line

I am working on a FileReader function which does a specific function depending on the line.

However the last line of the file I want to read is always blank for some reason, and that messes up my program.

Is there a way I can tell the program to stop at that point?

When trying to run it, I get the following output

> Starting program: 
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
>    what():  basic_string::substr
>   - - 1 1 Abort

And I know it is because of that blank line since I told the program to get specific elements on each line and those elements are null on that line.

Comment: It would help for us to see something that exhibits the problem you are having. Ideally a simple self contained example, or at least a chunk of your existing code.

Comment: Are you asking how to do nothing when a line is blank? Or are you asking how to know that a line is the last line?

Comment: @DrewDormann More specifically, I want to tell the computer to close the file when they reach that line. Not just taking it into account.

Comment: I bet there is while(!inFile.eof()) loop...

Comment: The first blank line? Or the last line? Or the last line, only if it's blank?

Comment: Last blank line. It'll always be blank in this case.

Comment: If a line is blank, check for eof. If so, close the file.

Comment: Just did that and it still gives me the same output.

Comment: Why should it "mess up" your program in the first place? Can't you just ignore blank lines?

Comment: I try to do that, but for some reason the program still wants to take the substring of a blank line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you have something like this:

```
std::ifstream file("file.txt");
std::string line;
while(getline(file,line)) {
  //read the line
}
```

I also gather (correct me if I'm wrong) that at the end of your file, you have TWO newlines, like this:

```
line1\nline2\n\n
```

If this is the case, the while loop body will for sure be executed on one empty line at the end. To get around this, just ignore the empty line:

```
while(getline(file,line)) {
  if (line == "") continue;
  //read the line
}
```

If this doesn't work, it's because I misunderstood your question, and in this case please provide some more details.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much, kind sir. You saved me from pulling my hair off!